# Git: check remote repository's config file

Tags: git

Is there a git command that allows the client side to read the remote repository's config file(s), e.g. for checking whether `core.sharedRepository` is set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is impossible, which seems to be a quite logical design choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this short of logging into the remote machine with SSH or the like. If you want to share configurations between repositories, you can create a `config` file in the root directory of your repo and commit it.